# View is null even after initialization

Tags: android, android-listview, nullpointerexception

I have a `listview` in my code and I want to set `adapter` on it.

But the issue is, even after initializing the `listview`, it is still **null** resulting into `nullPointerException`. (I checked it by logging and debugging)

I'm not able to access any view from that xml.

What am I missing? Any help appreciated.

**xml**

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:scrollbars="vertical" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/lvToday"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:divider="#FFF"
            android:dividerHeight="2dp" />

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/lvTomorrow"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/lvToday"
            android:divider="#FFF"
            android:dividerHeight="2dp" />
    </RelativeLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

---

**Activity file**

```
public class DashboardActivity extends Activity {

ListView lvToday, lvTomorrow;
TextView lblCall;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.dashboard);
    init();
}

private void init() {
    lvToday = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lvToday);
    lvTomorrow = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lvTomorrow);

    TodayAppAdapter adapter = new TodayAppAdapter(DashboardActivity.this,
            DashboardActivity.this);
                // This line is giving NULL
    lvToday.setAdapter(adapter);

    TomorrowAppAdapter adapter1 = new TomorrowAppAdapter(
            DashboardActivity.this, DashboardActivity.this);
                // This line is giving NULL
    lvTomorrow.setAdapter(adapter1);
}
}
```

Comment: check whether the XML name is  "dashboard"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) test eclipse menu: Project -> Clean...

2) if you have more than one version for your xml layout (example layout-large, layout-xlarge,...), check if all of them have your view.

Comment: it worked. The copy of xml in `layout` nad `layout-land` was different. Thats why this issue.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a TextView in your layout

Comment: it is there. it's my mistake that I've copy-pasted selected code only. Check my updated question.

Answer (score 0):

Put a `String []` 
along with name of your Adapter  in your

```
OnDraw()
```

Method